# Reformatting MacBookPro6,2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, recovery

I have a macbook pro 6,2 and don't have the recovery discs as I am traveling abroad and left my discs at home. Is there any way to reformat my hard drive and get it to factory (or near factory) settings without the discs?

Does my computer have a recovery partition and can I use that to reformat?

Answer (score 2):

All Lion and later (10.7) OS X should have a recovery HD by default.

If you haven't changed your configuration, it likely does still have the recovery partition.  Find out by holding Option while booting. Now, the recovery HD only has disk formatting tools and terminal and the ability to connect to the App Store to re-download the installer. It doesn't actually save the installer to the drive.

Barring that, I would download the Mac OS from the App Store and put it on a thumb drive for a reinstall.